# How to install rgl in OS X 10.14

Tags: r, homebrew, x11, rgl, xquartz

I am running a vanilla copy of R 3.5.2:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin18.2.0                
system         x86_64, darwin18.2.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.2                         
year           2018                        
month          12                          
day            20                          
svn rev        75870                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
nickname       Eggshell Igloo
```

R is installed via Homebrew:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.9.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision de1ec; last commit 2019-01-15)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 68a73e; last commit 2019-01-14)
```

I am trying to install the `rgl` package from within XQuartz 2.7.11 and the `xterm` application, and I get the following error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rgl':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: NULL
  error:        Loading rgl's DLL failed. 
        On MacOS, rgl depends on XQuartz, which you can download from xquartz.org.
```

Here is a screenshot to confirm that I am attempting the install from within the XQuartz `xterm` application:

[image: xterm screenshot]

Are there any additional steps required to configure Mac OS X 10.14 and XQuartz 2.7.11, which allows installation of `rgl`?

Comment: Did you compile rgl yourself, or download a binary?  I wouldn't expect a binary from CRAN to work with R from Homebrew.

Comment: Running `install.packages("rgl")` results in downloading source code and the subsequent compilation of `rgl` and its dependencies (as shown partially in the screenshot).

Comment: Were there any errors in the compiling/linking?

Comment: No, this the only error reported.

Comment: I think this needs someone with Homebrew expertise to explain how that could happen.  Alternatively, you could install the CRAN version of R (but then you'd need to re-install all other packages).  The binary of 'rgl' on CRAN works fine.

Comment: Just to confirm, removing Homebrew R and replacing it with CRAN R worked. I'd be curious to know why Homebrew R appears to be broken, though.

Comment: Good to hear you have a solution.  It might take a bounty to generate enough interest to get an answer to the Homebrew question.